# Does spring requires JTA TX manager when deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

I have a web application, deployed in Tomcat. This app depends on one Spring pojo app jar, whcih is available in the classpath.

Spring POJO app, contains some DAO's and few services, I'm accessing these DAO's and services in web app as beans, by loading the spring context using ClassPathXMLApplicationContext.

The Serivces in Spring app also uses the DAOs , in which case both the apps accessing the same DB. Spring POJO app uses HibernateTransactionManager.

For this scenario, HibernateTXManager is good, or Do I need to gor JTA?

Comment: No you don't need JTA transaction when accessing a single data source. You need it only if you are accessing more than a single data source, and you need two phase commit transactions.

Comment: Thanks Orid,  in that case, which Datasource option will be good, 1.DriverManagerDataSource 2. JNDI lookup for datasource using DataSourceTXManager , right now it is using DirverManagerDS.

Comment: @Murugesh, DriverManagerDataSource doesn't maintain any connection pooling, so don't use that. You can use DBCP for connection pooling, you can also configure the same in Tomcat and use it as a JNDI

Answer (score 0):

[JTA](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) is useful when you want to enlist two or more Datasources in the sam global transaction.

In your case you should have `Services` use `DAOs` and Web beans use `Services`, so this is just a Spring application design decision.

For connection pooling, I advice you take a look on [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), which is probably the [fastest one on the market](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/).

Comment: I will check out this option. Right now I'm using DataSourceTransactionManager and configured the spring to look for JNDI name by JndiObjectFactoryBean.